# selectpicker with select all by default

Tags: javascript, jquery, select, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using the selectpicker [plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/).
Now I am trying to select all the options by default, or at least a button to select all without the need of click in the dropdown.

Currently the demo only works if the dropdown is clicked and after that, click the button.

Any idea?

```
$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();


$(".btn_clk").click(function () {
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('selectAll');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tpnw96ed/

Comment: Apparently this has been raised as a bug already: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/721

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution in this [thread](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/721) works for me.

Here is the updated code of the plugin:

Line 888 and 895 in [boostrapt-select.js](https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/blob/master/js/bootstrap-select.js)

```
selectAll: function () {
  this.findLis();
  this.$lis.not('.divider').not('.disabled').not('.selected').not('.hide').find('a').click();
},

deselectAll: function () {
  this.findLis();
  this.$lis.not('.divider').not('.disabled').filter('.selected').not('.hide').find('a').click();
},
```

Note the change `.filter(':visible')`  is now  `.not('.hide')`

Answer (score 8):

There is default way to add **Select All** and **Deselect All** buttons to selectpicker now. You should use option `data-actions-box="true"` to enable buttons and `data-select-all-text="Select all buttton name" data-deselect-all-text="Deselect all button name"` to rename them

Answer (score 4):

You can open/close the Selectpicker before/after clicking the button:

```
$(".btn_clk").click(function () {
    $('.dropdown-menu').css("display","block");
    $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('selectAll');
    $('.dropdown-menu').css("display","none");
});
```

**Edit:** You will also need to add the following to manually trigger the dropdown on clicks after a selectAll:

```
$('.selectpicker').click(function () {
    if($('.dropdown-menu').css("display") == "block") $('.dropdown-menu').css("display","none");
    else $('.dropdown-menu').css("display","block");
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tpnw96ed/7/)

Comment: Yes, that's a workaround to this bug: https://github.com/silviomoreto/bootstrap-select/issues/721

Comment: It appears this is the only way... There is a show method, but that doesn't seem to work. And it will only select all items when the dropdown is open.

Comment: the dropdown will be broken after the click, right?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('val', ['Mustard','Relish', 'Ketchup']);
```

Comment: This isn't really maintainable, is it?